# Puppet: How to honor install_options of package() if specific package is installed already

Tags: debian, puppet, apt

*If one thinks of a better title for this question: Please change it accordingly.*

**Environment:**

- Debian jessie 8.5
- puppet master: 3.8.5
- puppet agent: 3.7.2
- apt: 1.0.9.8.3

**Problem:**

A specific package is installed already on the node, let's take `needrestart` for example:

```
# dpkg -l | grep needrestart
ii  needrestart                     1.2-8+deb8u1
```

Using the following code:

```
package{[
  'needrestart',
]:
  ensure          => installed, # latest won't work, either
  install_options => ['-t', 'jessie-backports']
}
```

I would expect that `needrestart` is reinstalled / upgraded to the version out of `jessie-backports`. However, this doesn't happen, there is no reinstall / upgrade happening. Inside the (debug) logs there's nothing worth to be shown regarding this.

**Solution:**

In case this is not intended: Anyone knows a clever way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that your `install_options` will only be used if the package resource is *actually installing* your packages. You have a few options:

- Use `ensure => latest` and hope for a package update (or trigger one yourself) - probably not what you want.
- Upgrading to Puppet 4.x. Since version 4, Puppet has [reinstall_on_refresh](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#package-attribute-reinstall_on_refresh), which allows a reinstall on a `notify` event, if the provider supports `reinstallable`. While this works on Debian, this option is probably not useable for you.
- Trick Puppet into thinking the package is uninstalled - this would need a puppet patch on your local installation, not recommended.
- Patch Puppet with reinstallation capabilities: In [this bug report](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4976) from a few years ago, Aggelos Economopoulos supplied [a patch](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/attachments/download/1155/force.patch) for some version of puppet, which looks rather simple. This should get you started. I do not recommend patching your puppet agent installations, though.
- Reinstall it yourself: Probably the only option you have for now: Write something along these lines:

  ```
  exec { "apt-get reinstall $package $your_options":
      user   => 'root',
      onlyif => 'dpkg -s $package| grep 'Version $your_version'
  }
  ```

  Depending on the differences of the packages with and without options, this can be arbitrarily hard. If only a handful of packages are affected, it can be managable.
- Write your own provider and add it to `package`, or establish something like `package_reinstall`: It is surprisingly easy, can be managed and versioned via a module, and works without a Puppet update. I suggest starting with [provider/package/apt.rb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/3.1.x/lib/puppet/provider/package/apt.rb). This might be your best option after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, back then. I'm using `APT pinning` since a while quite extensively, with great success, and it solve{d,s} the problem in a nice and elegant manner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ensure => installed` will only make sure it is installed, but it won't upgrade if there is a newer version.  Use `latest` to do that.  It will also only upgrade if there is a newer version.  If that is a preferred version you want that is older than the version that is currently installed, you will have to find a way to work around that.  Perhaps an `exec` that will check if current installed version is different than the version in that other repo, then uninstall if it is, and let the package resource install the correct version after.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Regarding `ensure => latest`: I've tested this before, doesn't work, forgot to note this - sorry! Regarding `exec`: Yeah, this would be a possibility, but it feels quite 'hackish', doesn't it? I wonder if there isn't a better option / way / route ...

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with apt, but with yum, downgrades don't work that well, because it may have a lot of dependencies that require downgrading.  You end up having to manually downgrade any dependencies also.  I'm not sure there is a way (with the package providers that are provided) to do that.  It is possible that `ensure => latest` doesn't use the parameters to check, only to do the actual install.

Comment: Actually, it's (at least in my case) a upgrade, and not a downgrade, still the disadvantages (might) apply. In Debian, the backports mechanism is a way to get more recent versions of software into the stable release. So, a quite common situation is: There is a machine, which a specific software and version installed. Now, a more recent version get's available via backports. It would be nice if there would be a way to then pull in the package out of the backports repo, but I'm not sure if this is possible at all. Maybe I'll have to ask on the mailing list...

Comment: Yeah, the only thing I'm guessing is that it doesn't apply the options to the check, only to the actual install/upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to trigger the install action for the **install_options** to take effect. A possible workaround is to first `ensure => absent`, and then once the package is removed you can `ensure => present` or `ensure => 1.2-8+deb8u1` and the subsequent install will honor **install_options**.

Comment: This would involve changing the code two times, in my opinion not really a "clever" way for which I'm looking. Besides: If the package in question is a daemon, it's not really possible to first remove it and afterwards install it again, because then the service is interrupted for a longer time, than just an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `APT pinning` quite extensively since a while, and I believe this is (one of) the cleanest solutions out there, especially if combined with `unattended upgrades` and / or a regular `apt-get dist-upgrade`.